# Amazon S3 Java SDK copyObject permission denied after copying

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

we are using Amazon S3 with JDK copyObject method to copy objects from one bucket to another. Copying is automated. User1 uploads files manually to source bucket, systemUser transfers to destination bucket. User1 is source and destination bucket owner.

```
s3.copyObject(sourceBucket, objectKey, destinationBucket, objectKey);
```

Copy works, but after copying User1 is not able to access the copied object in destination bucket. Access denied. Copied objects owner after copying in destination bucket is systemUser. Also tried modifying the acl of the copied object in destination.

```
s3.setObjectAcl(destinationBucket, objectKey, acl);
```

This also gives Access Denied.

How can we copy the object so that the User1 (who copied to source bucket and is the owner of source and destination bucket) can reach the file in destination bucket?

Comment: How did you solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to retention policy we could not edit the file (and the permissions) after copying. We switched to CopyObjectRequest which has an option to specify ACL before copying and give it as an argument to the copy action.